# How to identify "the central action of a sentence"?

Tags: verbs

I need to identify "the central action of each sentence", defined as "the most important/central verb phrase."

I am unsure about how to determine which verb phrase is "the most important." For example:

1. "The film **exemplifies** this representation and **opened** a door to transforming the genre."

^ I'm confused whether it's "exemplifies" or "opened". I think if it were an independent + dependent clause, the "most important verb phrase" would be the one in the independent clause -- but in this sentence, it is two independent clauses joined together by a conjunction.

And this also gets confusing for more complex examples, like these:

2. "The film **starts** with the moment the bird is rescued and re-homed and we **follow** its journey to recovery as it adjusts to the new environment."

^ I have excluded "is rescued and re-homed" because I believe that's a dependent clause? And "adjusts" because it follows "as..." therefore making it less important to "[we] follow".

3. "This **is** also when the narration plays and we **realise** the tale is being told from the bird’s perspective.

^ Same here, I have excluded "plays" because it comes after "when..." so it's less important than the verb "is"; and "is being told" because I think that's a that-clause (implied 'that').

Comment: Define your own "main verb" in your question because it doesn't seem to be following any established nomenclature.

Comment: Changing it to "central action" makes it more confusing, not less.

Comment: @alphabet Ahh sorry!! I'm not the one defining it, so I don't really know. It's just supposed to be "the most important verb/action" in the sentence...

Comment: Applying the term 'actor' to _the film_ in the first set of examples is dubious at best. It's the grammatical subject, but not a person or animate being performing some action. It's certainly erroneous in #2 where its grammatical role is subject of **was directed by Danny Miller**, but it is certainly being acted upon - _Danny Miller directed **the film**_. Better to just think of it as subject instead of trying to apply a semantic label.

Comment: @DW256 Oh, I see. My mistake! I call it character/actor because in our textbook, it says the character/actor isn't necessarily "a person or animate being performing some action" - it can also be abstract/conceptual (e.g. nominalisations). And the reason the textbook differentiates actor/character from subject is because they define subject as something else.

Comment: @Dee These definitions (and their source) should be included in your question.

Comment: 'Most important' here looks very much as if it is being judged so on interpretational grounds. One could argue that this is not a question that is appropriate for the ELU website, and would not be even if there were an obvious answer. As it is, two very different statements are made in the verb phrases; if pressed, I'd say the question is akin to asking one to rank chalk and cheese. A teacher 100 years ago and a mouse might well give different answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed. I'm *guessing* OP means "a verb that isn't in some sort of subordinate clause," but then it isn't clear why they think (1)-(3) have only one main verb.

Comment: @alphabet. Yes. [Nathaniel George, in a University of Nevada article](https://www.unr.edu/writing-speaking-center/student-resources/writing-speaking-resources/parenthetical-phrases#:~:text=In%20essence%2C%20a%20parenthetical%20is,sentence%20without%20disrupting%20the%20flow.), writes [adjusted]: '... [A] parenthetical is just a phrase that is not [syntactically] essential to the rest of the sentence. _However, just because it isn’t essential does not mean that it isn’t important_. When used correctly, a parenthetical can add _crucial_ new information to a sentence without disrupting the flow.'

Comment: ... This spells out the difference between 'higher in some perceived syntactic hierarchy' (parentheticals being 'mere' adjuncts) and 'conveying the most important information'. // I suppose in '2', 'the bird' 'outranks' the anaphor 'its [journey ...]'. But "the most important/central verb phrase" is an unusable definition. Try with 'I came, I saw, I conquered.'

Answer (score 1):

This is not to answer your question, since I find your question as is virtually unanswerable.

What this is is my answer to your confusion that I think renders your question unanswerable.

There are three major misconceptions that you seem to have:

> (1) All verbs denote "actions". Correction: But verbs like "be" don't denote an action.
> (2) All subjects denote "actors". Correction: But subjects can play many different roles including but not limited to "actors" (i.e., agents).
> (3) You need only one verb in a sentence. Correction: Actually, a sentence can have any number of verbs; therefore, it's natural that you have two or more verbs in a single sentence.